# WPF/MVVM: How to reference the View from the ViewModel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding

Consider a fairly classic/simple MVVM construct with items that are displayed using Xaml-bindings to ViewModels for each item, respectively. The items are selectable and the ViewModels have an `IsSelected` property that raises a `PropertyChanged` event for a design-relevant property, e.g. `BorderBrush`, so that the UI can update itself properly.

The required mouse interaction is done by listening to tunneling and bubbeling events of the parent container, evaluating `e.OriginalSource.DataContext` and ultimately setting `ViewModel.IsSelected` one way or the other.

This works fine, if the "design-relevant" changes can be handled by the bound control alone, but I would like to add an `Adorner` for each selected item/control and use that to highlight specific user interactions, e.g. select, move, resize. This is not a problem, if the interaction starts on and only affects one of the ViewModel-bound controls, because then the control is known within my code's scope. But, if multiple items are selected (e.g. via a "select all" command), how do I access the View/control of all affected ViewModels so that I can create an `Adorner` for each one that can use the target control's visuals, position or size?

I understand the MVVM principle (or the intention behind it) that the ViewModel should not depend on the View, but I don't see any other way and am wondering how best to implement a solution.

Currently my approach would include something like this:

```
public interface IViewModel{
    FrameworkElement Element {get; set;}
}

public partial class MyItemControl : UserControl
{
    public MyItemControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (e.NewValue as IViewModel)?.Element = this;
    }
}
```

Is there another way, e.g. via Xaml bindings? Usually I do not prefer pure Xaml solutions, but in this case it would help me avoid requirements for the controls - or me requiring to use controls at all.

And: is this indeed a violation of the mentioned principle?

Answer (score 1):

The view model should never, ever access the view directly. No exceptions. Over the past 15 years I've worked on some extremely challenging WPF apps, and I've never once encountered a case that couldn't be solved elegantly without breaking this fundamental rule.

To answer your question, there are several ways of doing this, although which implementation you choose will depend on your circumstances. One of the easiest is to use a behavior. You give that behavior some dependency properties, which you bind to INPC properties in your view model, and you write code there to create/update your adorners accordingly.

Bear in mind though that behaviors are really just another form of code-behind, albeit slightly more abstracted. A lot of people fall into the trap of using behaviors and converters to implement functionality that can be easily implemented with things like DataTriggers. Again, the specifics will depend on exact what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll postpone my decision regarding the implementation details.